# How to travese a MATLAB table w/o creating a new table

Tags: matlab

I wanted to travel a table w/o creating a new table. MATLAB has a rowfun API. But it does not like a lambda with no return type. Is there a better to do so?

```
>> T = table({1;2;3})

T = 

Var1
____

[1] 
[2] 
[3] 

>> rowfun(@(x) display('') , T)
Error using table/rowfun>dfltErrHandler (line 338)
Applying the function '@(x)display('')' to the 1st row of A generated the following error:

Too many output arguments.


Error in      table/rowfun>@(s,varargin)dfltErrHandler(grouped,funName,s,varargin{:}) (line 200)
errHandler = @(s,varargin) dfltErrHandler(grouped,funName,s,varargin{:});

Error in table/rowfun (line 219)
            [b_data{i,:}] = errHandler(struct('identifier',ME.identifier, 'message',ME.message,
            'index',i),inArgs{:});

>> rowfun(@(x) x , T)

ans = 

Var1
____

[1] 
[2] 
[3]
```

Comment: What is an actual use case for what you're trying to accomplish? Pasting code without any explanation isn't very useful for others attempting to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @excaza Maybe display is a special API. It is available to me. >> which display
built-in (<...>/toolbox/matlab/lang/@cell/display)  % cell method. I wanted to traverse a table like what we can do for array. For example, arrayfun(@(x) display(''), table2array(T)) works.

Comment: oops, missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short story

Use the following syntax for calling `rowfun` if you don't expect an explicit output:

```
rowfun(@(x) display(''), T, 'NumOutputs', 0)
```

Given the following example:

```
T = table({1;2;3});

fprintf('rowfun:\n')
rowfun(@(x) display(''), T, 'NumOutputs', 0, 'OutputFormat', 'uniform');
fprintf('arrayfun:\n')
arrayfun(@(x) display(''), table2array(T))
```

We get a consistent return:

```
>> testcode
rowfun:
     ''

     ''

     ''

arrayfun:
     ''

     ''

     ''
```

## Short story long

The error is based on `rowfun` expecting to have to provide an output in some kind of format (table, cell, etc.), so its default is to expect at least one output argument from the function handle it's using.

You can find the relevant portions in `rowfun`'s source (`open rowfun`):

```
pnames = {'GroupingVariables' 'InputVariables' 'OutputFormat' 'NumOutputs' 'OutputVariableNames' 'SeparateInputs' 'ExtractCellContents'  'ErrorHandler'};
dflts =  {                []               []              2            1                    {}             true                 false              [] };
[groupVars,dataVars,outputFormat,nout,outNames,separateArgs,extractCells,errHandler,supplied] ...
    = matlab.internal.table.parseArgs(pnames, dflts, varargin{:});
```

and

```
try
    if nout > 0
        [b_data{i,:}] = fun(inArgs{:});
    else
        fun(inArgs{:});
    end
catch ME
    if nout > 0
        [b_data{i,:}] = errHandler(struct('identifier',ME.identifier, 'message',ME.message, 'index',i),inArgs{:});
    else
        errHandler(struct('identifier',ME.identifier, 'message',ME.message, 'index',i),inArgs{:});
    end
end
```

As you can see, the default number of outputs is `1` and, unless you call `rowfun` with an explicit `'NumOutputs', 0` NV pair, it's going to expect an output from `display`, which will obviously cause the error.